# How can I share a console program over the network?

Tags: telnet, mud

I'm looking for some kind of TELNET daemon for linux to share a single app.

I wrote a BBS/MUD, but no networking routines, and I'm looking for a way to "share" the app, in a way Citrix XenApp works for GUI/Windows Apps. I remember I used such a server once, for console mode applications, but I cannot recall the name/internet address.

Comment: Why not just use a SSH server?

Comment: How do I do that? Can I bypass the login mechanism? (my app uses its own...)

Comment: Why would you want to bypass it? Just use your normal username/pass or create a guest account that all the users can share.

Comment: And then I specify my app as shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, it's pretty much unheard of to rely on a sharing layer on top of a MUD to handle sockets rather than having the socket code within the MUD server, not least because using such a layer, it seems like it would be very difficult to have the MUD actually be multiplayer.

You might want to look at integrating [SocketMUD](http://www.socketmud.dk/) with your project; SocketMUD is basically a bare-bones socket handling layer intended for MUD use, so could be exactly what you need.